# Using awk to search whole file for matches to field 1

Tags: awk

I have an input file like this with many records in(however they are comma delimited):

```
ALBAN SQUARE,SGWAR ALBAN 
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET
test1,test2                        
ALBERT PLACE,MAES ALBERT                         
ALBERT STREET,STRYD ALBERT                        
ALBERT STREET,HEOL GWYNN                          
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET
test1,test2
```

I want to be able to search the whole file for field1, if field one appears in either column1 or column2 more than once I want this line to be printed to a csv file. If however it only appears once I want this to print to another csv file. So my output would be:

repeated.csv

```
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET                         
ALBERT STREET,STRYD ALBERT                        
ALBERT STREET,HEOL GWYNN
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET
test1,test2
test1,test2
```

diff.csv

```
ALBAN SQUARE,SGWAR ALBAN                         
ALBERT PLACE,MAES ALBERT
```

At the moment the output is for repeated is:

```
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET
test1,test2                        
ALBERT STREET,STRYD ALBERT                        
ALBERT STREET,HEOL GWYNN                          
HEOL GWYNN,ALBERT STREET
test1,test2
```

I want the matches to be below eachother in the output as shown above.

Is this possible to do in awk?

I tried:

```
BEGIN{ FS=","; } 
{ count[$1]++; 
  if (count[$1] == 1) first[$1] = $0; 
  if (count[$1] == 2) print first[$1]; 
  if (count[$1] > 1) print; 
}
End{ }
```

Comment: I tried: BEGIN{
FS=",";
}
{

    count[$1]++;

 
    if (count[$1] == 1)
        first[$1] = $0;


    if (count[$1] == 2)
        print first[$1];

    if (count[$1] > 1)
        print;
}

End{
}

Comment: but that only checks column 1 @fedorqui

Comment: @Amy you should [edit] your question to include your attempt.

Comment: Don;t show us input in one format and then say `however they are comma delimited` - show us the comma delimited file. We're going to use what you post to test a potential solution against so showing us something that's not what you actually have is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next}
     {file="diff";
      if (a[$1]>1 || a[$2]>1) file="repeated";
      print > file
     }' file file
```

I assume the columns are tab separated.

Note this uses something similar to what you explain you did. The key here is to keep track of how many times every field appeared, on the first loop.

On the second loop, we check if any of the fields appeared more than once; if so, we set the output file to "repeated" (name it csv1,2 or whatever); otherwise, the file is the "diff". Then, it outputs the line to the file.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next} {file="diff"; if (a[$1]>1 || a[$2]>1) file="repeated"; print > file}' a a
$ cat diff
ALBAN SQUARE    SGWAR ALBAN
ALBERT PLACE    MAES ALBERT
$ cat repeated 
ALBERT STREET   STRYD ALBERT
ALBERT STREET   HEOL GWYNN
HEOL GWYNN      ALBERT STREET
```

---

Run it either with the one-liner I mentioned in the "Test" section or saving it into an `awk` file:

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; next}
     {file="diff";
      if (a[$1]>1 || a[$2]>1) file="repeated";
      print > file
}

$ awk -f script.awk file file
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, I am using command prompt and notepad to create my awk script on windows "awk.exe -f script.awk inputfile". How can I get this to work using that format? @fedorqui

Comment: @Amy just place this script in a `script.awk` file and run it!

Comment: I have this in my script.awk: BEGIN{
FS=",";
FNR==NR
}
{


for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
a[$i]++; next

} 



{

file="diff";

if (a[$1]>1 || a[$2]>1)

file="repeated";

print > file
}

End{
}

and ran AWK.EXE -f script.awk dedupedpwwp.csv

but nothing is happening.. @fedorqui

Comment: @Amy check my update. Also, note nothing is being shown in the stdout because the lines are being written into files.

Comment: no files are being created, do I have to create a diff and repeated file first? Sorry I am just really confused @fedorqui

Comment: @Amy you have to provide the file twice: `AWK.EXE -f script.awk dedupedpwwp.csv dedupedpwwp.csv`

Comment: is there anyway this could be altered so that the output has all the ones that match field 1 together in the list? At the moment it outputs my results as it appears in the input file, I want the matches to be grouped together. Thanks @fedorqui

Comment: @Amy not sure what do you mean here. Could you edit your question and show some representative sample input together with its desired output?

Comment: @Amy note your files have trailing spaces. Say `cat -vet file` to see these spaces after the end of most of the lines. Is this correct?

Comment: @Amy `awk` cannot do this in a straight forward way, because this needs storing all the file in memory and then sorting and printing. Since it is a matter of sorting, just get the `repeated` file and sort it with --> `sort repeated`.

Answer (score 2):

another similar `awk` with double pass

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;a[$2]++;next} 
              $1 in a{if(a[$1]==1) print > "ones"; 
                      else print > "multi"
                     }' file{,}
```

results

```
$ cat multi
ALBERT STREET   STRYD ALBERT
ALBERT STREET   HEOL GWYNN
HEOL GWYNN      ALBERT STREET

$ cat ones
ALBAN SQUARE    SGWAR ALBAN
ALBERT PLACE    MAES ALBERT
```

UPDATE

you can save a few more keystrokes

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;a[$2]++;next} 
              $1 in a{print > (a[$1]==1?"ones":"multi")}' file{,}
```

**Explanation:** compute the counts of fields in positions 1 and 2 in the first pass.  Second time around check the count of field 1, if it's exactly one output to "ones" if it's more to "multi".

Note that multiple counts of the fields in second position is counted as well but if the value never appears in first position it won't be checked against in the second pass.  This simplifies the logic little bit.

Comment: saying `print $0` is not needed, `print` alone suffices.

Comment: OK, +1  although your answer would benefit from some explanations. Also, we are using different logics here. You are just checking if the first field has been seen.

Comment: thanks, ".. field1, if field one appears in either column1 or column2 more than once.." is what I implemented.  added explanation

Comment: question: to pass multiple files in 1 awk, you use `}' file1, file2` ?

Comment: `file1 file2` without comma.  this script is doublepass reads the same file twice.  Here I'm using the bash brace extension trick `file{,}` resolves to `file file`, ensuring that the same file name provided twice.